# wifi connectivity issue

Tags: wi-fi

I have issue connecting my wifi 
It shows error as refuse to connect with chrome but if i search it display content but as i go on any content gives me error 
Even youtube not working even 
Playstore  home page only gets loaded but when i select any app shows check your connection and try again 
Also whats app and fb working fine 
But 
None of the app apart from this works
I am using samsung on 7 
With 5.1 version  and rooted by king root previously working fine 
And the same exact error was also in my previous phone  and it gets resolved automatically and happens randomly some time

Only on my phone not working reset all phone working fine on even pc not instagram  as on insta i could only see pages being loaded but not images displayed
And also operamini 7.2 version works fine even i can completley browse but cannot download
My phone is rooted  i was using adblocker i uninstall it even adaway i qas using uninstall it 
I tried changing dns as 8.8.8.8  google still same

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking here.

Comment: Try resetting your router/ access point

Answer (score 0):

Reset the router if that doesn't work forget the wifi and the re get it